# How to reduce Diffie Hellman problem to ElGamal?

Tags: diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption, reduction

[image]

I'm trying to answer without success questions (ii - iv)

Any hint will be appreciated :)

Comment: Look at the right on the related links of this page!

Comment: Thanks but all those are other cases

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18007/18298

Comment: Book for you [Mathematics of Public Key Cryptography](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/crypto-book.html)

Comment: Thanks, i have already seen it